# How to stretch arrays in LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, arrays, fractions

When I make arrays in LyX with fractions they always come out overlapping with each other, so I decided to figure out how to prevent that. After some searching I figured out that the two ways is to either add spacing between lines manually (which I have no idea how to do in LyX) or stretch the array with a command. After some more searching I found someone else asking the same question on another website and they were told that this is discussed in the *Math* section in LyX Help.
[image: What the]

Now, after having found the specific command *\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{stretchfactor}*, the issue still remains of me not having the slightest clue of how to actually use this in LyX. When I try to use TeX mode it just does not seem to recognize the command and nothing actually happens.

As such, after a lot of trying, I throw in the towel and come here to ask if someone else has a clue of how to make this work.
Thank you.

Comment: arrays should not overlap and if you increase arraystretch they get bigger and should still not overlap show some generated latex and an image of the output you get otherwise it is hard to guess the issue

Comment: In addition to David's advice, please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. By the way, welcome to tex.se!