# How to arraystretch in LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, arrays, fractions

When I make arrays with fractions in LyX, **see picture attached** happens, and I do not know how to fix it. For more info see [minimal example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ar-ip1buNiwQo-VPxEADNIfp1YsjzDr2/view?usp=sharing).

Also, despite doing a minimal amount of searching and finding that the *Math* section of built in help tab **see second picture** I have no idea how to actually input the command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{stretchfactor}` so it doesn't help.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Horrible]
[image: This tells me nothing]

Comment: Is that the same question like this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616898/how-to-stretch-arrays-in-lyx  ?

Comment: It's better to use the `cellspace` package and to set `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` to a nonzero value. As I don't use Lyx, I don't know how this is done, but in pure latex, it is written in the preamble, and the column specifiers are prefixed with the letter `S`.

Comment: @Mensch Yes it is, I thought I had to make a new question, though now I understand maybe there is a way to just update the old one, not entirely sure how though

Comment: You can edit your question ...